# Jquery - Div with link inside and jq.click() function

Tags: jquery, triggers, hyperlink, click

Is it possible to disable the jquery click when a href link (inside the clickable div) was clicked?

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">
    <a href="http://google.de">google</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#test').click(function() {
        alert('the link was not clicked'); 
    });
});
```

**example**
http://jsfiddle.net/QHQcQ/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but adding -

```
 $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

would prevent the link click from firing and also stop the link click bubbling up to the 'div' click event.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/Lf3hL/

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to the `return false` in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729372/jquery-div-with-link-inside-and-jq-click-function/7729540#7729540).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may use

```
$('#test').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
});
```

event.preventDefault() to make the click not work

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the click event on the `a` bubbling up to `div#test`. You can do that like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() {
        alert('the link was not clicked'); 
    });
    $('#test a').click(function(e) {
        return false;

        //equivalent to:
        //    e.stopPropagation();
        //    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/QHQcQ/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the event or simply return false:

http://jsbin.com/aliwih/edit#source

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#test').click(function() { 
      $("#hello").text('the link was not clicked'); 
      return false;
  });
  $('#test a').click(function() { 
     $("#hello").text('the link clicked'); 
     return false;
  });
});
```